# Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'e_sqlite3.dll'

Tags: c#, uwp, package, nuget-package

Whenever I am trying to build the project I am getting the above mentioned error.
I do not know whats happening. The last thing I did in my project is I had uninstalled Sqlite-net-Pcl packages. But, now I have installed them back still I am getting this error.
I also tried deleting the folders in the packages(c:) but it get regenerated.
Please help me in this. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your packages are compiled for different framework versions. You might need to check your `packages.config` and or `csproj` files.

Comment: I ran into this issue when upgrading AppCenter NuGet packages to Version 3.0.  Still don't have a solution.